# Approach for a multi period scheduling quadratic optimization model in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, quadratic-programming

I aim to develop an optimization model in Python for the supply of substance A based on the DA electricity prices. The desired output of the model is an hourly flow planning for the next day. I have drafted the following quadratic objective function:

[obj function](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?min(%5Csum_%7Bt=1%7D%5E%7B24%7D%5Csum_%7Bi=1%7D%5E%7BN%7D&space;DLC_%7Bt,i%7D&space;%5Ctimes&space;%5Cphi_%7Bt,i%7D&space;%5Ctimes&space;%5Cfrac%7B%5Cphi_%7Bt,i%7D%7D%7Bc_%7Bi%7D%7D&space;%5Ctimes&space;e_%7Bi%7D&space;%5Ctimes&space;P_%7Bt%7D)&space;&space;&space;)

in which the subscript i (or set N) specifies the unit: production unit I, II, III or the injection or extraction unit, phi depicts the flow for each unit (decision variables). DLC is a binary value which simulates the on/off button for each unit. Energy consumption e (kWh/m3) is the consumption at max capacity, which is scaled based on the flow. The function is subject to a set of linear constraints.

I could find little on multi-period quadratic optimization on-line and, therefore, I came here with my three questions:

1. Is solving this as a quadratic programming problem the right approach or are there linearization methods which could simplify the problem?
2. How can I model the multi-period scheduling element within Python?
3. What is the most user-friendly and suitable package to model this with in Python?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would look real hard at that objective function to see if it can be made linear, or see if there is a linear substitute that would generate the same result for your decision variables.  If the `phi` variable is properly constrained elsewhere in the model by the on/off `DLC` variable, then you can throw out `DLC` in the objective.  Then look at the `phi` squared, which isn't explained very well and see if a more standard cost function or a piecewise linear representation is OK

Comment: I like `pyomo` for an optimization framework, but there are others.  depending on whether you can linearize, you'll need to find an appropriate solver.  Here's an example of a (relatively) complicated time period model for a gas plant that might give you some ideas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453375/pyomo-optimisation-not-working-gas-plant-dispatch/71490094#71490094

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I thought of trying to get rid of the DLC variable, but the phi variable can be either 0 or somewhere between 42.000 and 60.000 m3/h. I couldn't find how to adopt/model this within the constraints.

Comment: It isn't clear from your limited model description, but are you saying that phi can be nonzero when the "machine" is off, as annotated by `DLC`?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the mahcine is either off and then the flow should be zero or on and then the flow is within a certain region.

Comment: Then your formulation is incorrect (redundant) and DLC does not need to be in that equation.  It should be in a linear constraint elsewhere in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

It is possible to solve this problem as a quadratic programming problem, but it may be easier to linearize the objective function using a method like McCormick relaxation. This can help to simplify the problem and make it more tractable.

To model the multi-period scheduling element, you can use decision variables to represent the flows for each hour of the planning horizon. These decision variables can be optimized subject to the appropriate constraints.

There are several packages that you can use to model this problem in Python. Some popular options include CVXPY, Pyomo, and Gurobi. It is best to choose a package that is well-documented and has a supportive community, so that you can easily find help and resources if you need them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. From what I can find of McCormick relaxation,  this method is used on non-convex problems. I assumed my problem was convex as the matrix Q in the quadratic programming formulation, 1/2 xT * Q * x, is positive definite. Is this statement incorrect and is the problem indeed non-convex. If so, would you mind to explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

As this is convex, you can use a bunch of linear equations to force staying close to the quadratic curve.

[image]

So replace Φ<sup>2</sup> by z with

```
z ≥ Φ^2
```

which we approximate by

```
z ≥ a[k]*Φ+b[k]
```

for points along the `z=Φ^2` curve.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to apply this and come back with the results :)